# C++ linking error unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors

I have a project that includes files from a different project. I am getting linking errors...

> "unresolved external symbol "public: _*cdecl classA::classA(void"
>   (??()classA @@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "class classA **_cdecl
>   functionB(char const*)" (?functionB@@YAPEAVClassA@@PEBD@Z)...

and other 125 errors of the same type (after the constructor, which is the error I just listed, every function from the class I use is mentioned in one of the link errors).
The path for including the files of the second project is included in my property sheet. That project, on its own, builds fine.
I have tried to add that project to my solution, and add it as a dependency. No help. I have tried to add the dll that it creates in the project - linker - input. No help. 
In Configuration properties, the Runtime Library is set to /MTd.
I have even tried to add extern "C" in front of my include. No help.
I have tried to build them with Debug or Release, x64 or Win32. I prefer Release x64 but I'll take anything. 
Could you please help me - tell me what am I doing wrong, or where to look to fix this problem ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have no templates in any of the projects.

Comment: You can check out Visual Studio help with appropriate Error Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my dependencies in the Link - Input were being removed by the fact that I didn't explicitly specify that I can have dependencies in the property sheet. After changing the property sheet, I finally was able to create a dll.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the project which yours depends on, it should produce both a lib and a dll. You need to link that lib with your project. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757037/unresolved-external-symbols-in-visual-studio-2010) thread for a screenshot of how to link the lib in your project.

Comment: I have tried that - I listed that attempt in the third paragraph of my question. It did not make any difference. I was still getting the same errors.

Comment: @user1217150 you said you tried to link the dll, not the lib.

Comment: @user1217150 I suspect the problem is name mangling / calling conventions. Name mangling shouldn't be an issue with `cdecl`... Have you verified both the header declaration and cpp definition of the functions use `_cdecl`? You might try removing `_cdecl` from everything and recompiling the library project, and see if that helps.