# Visual Studio doesn't compile, ATL error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, atl

I have uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio 2013 and always the same error on compiling:

`Error 1837 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl ATL::_AtlInitializeCriticalSectionEx(struct _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION *,unsigned long,unsigned long)" (?_AtlInitializeCriticalSectionEx@ATL@@YAHPAU_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION@@KK@Z) referenced in function "public: long __thiscall ATL::CComCriticalSection::Init(void)" (?Init@CComCriticalSection@ATL@@QAEJXZ)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbols in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757037/unresolved-external-symbols-in-visual-studio-2010), as well as dozens of other "unresolved externals" questions here. Please do some research first before posting a new question. In this case, search for `[c++] unresolved external symbol` (with the square brackets). The post I linked has specific, step by step instructions.

Comment: You are forgetting to link atls.lib

Comment: I never linked it, and If I'm forgetting to like that lib, shouldn't there be more than just 1 unresolved external symbol?

Comment: You could always search the web for "LNK2019" before posting to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this function is membe of the atls.lib, Check your [/verbose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) inker output if this library is included.

The command *link /dump /symbols atls.lib* Shows me that this Symbol is defined in that file and is included in my ATL projects.

Answer (score -1):

it is very probably, that you are trying to compile sources that have included
their own atl header file implementation, just for compatibility satisfaction. In that case there in header files must be some pre-processor definition e.g. VBOX_COM_NO_ATL, which will tell not to use ATL at all.

to find the conflict - include **atlcore.h** in your source and see if it conflicts with some another atl header in your library/source code.